# Is it a good idea to use zlib as database

Tags: c++, encryption, zlib

I want know whether it a good idea to have all program option in a zlib.

Well the point is this: my program has lots of configuration files, they're updated concurrently from different threads. As a requirement, all files need a sort of checksum and some of them must be encrypted.

My idea is to have a compressed folder in a way that it's more difficult for other people discover what those files are for.

So is it a good idea to encrypt and compress them?

Comment: Although it doesn't meet your requirement of encrypted archive or multi-threading, you can look at PhysFS: http://icculus.org/physfs/. But here's the thing, if you want your archive to be thread-safe all 'edit' requests should ideally go through a single process so that it would take care of thread-safety between different requests to modify the archive. As for encryption, you mentioned that only certain files need to be encrypted, so just encrypt those files and store them in archive, why encrypt the entire archive?

Comment: My idea was compression -> encryption -> file

Comment: Are you talking about compressing the entire files in a folder to a compressed file and encrypting that compressed file to another file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compression *after* encryption is a *bad* idea. Why? Because good encryption looks like pure random numbers - and pure random numbers don't compress.

Amusingly enough the results of compression should also look like pure random numbers - because anything that isn't random is, in theory, compressible. Still - the idea of encryption is to prevent the unwanted from decrypting whereas compression is designed to be uncompressed.

Comment: If you wanted to compress *before* encryption, though, that probably wouldn't hurt.